# Ways to improve the "download" time from web server

Tags: performance, apache, static, download

We know that we can improve the **download** response time when we put static file on the Apache/Nginx server.(We can enable gzip and we can choice a better CDN network as well, or add expire time on the header to cache that at local).

My question is that any other better way/new technology to improve this issue?

So I also know this [post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/12/15/controljs-part-1/) from Steve Souders about "concurrently download static file"

Thanks in adv

Vance

Answer (score 0):

Store most frequently used files in memory cache.
Build a cluster to do load balancing.
Use SSD to store files. (An expensive method)

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at the [mod_zip caching](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/cache.htm) is another choice.